# Why does my user info disappear when viewing a badge?

Tags: bug, badges, user-interface

On any of the three sites (SO, SF and Meta), I can click through to an individual badge to see who has earned it. For example:

https://serverfault.com/badges/9/autobiographer

When I view an individual badge, my user info disappears from the page header. The whole header section collapses to "about", "faq" and the search box.

Hopefully this isn't just me. Is it intentional, or a bug? If the former, what's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Not just you, can't speak to whether its a bug or a feature

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon/92060#92060

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The users page used to have that issue. It was recently changed back. It's probably the same issue. I agree this one should be changed back too.