# When you click a badge description. The titlebar with your info shrinks

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my user info disappear when viewing a badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/why-does-my-user-info-disappear-when-viewing-a-badge)

When I goto [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question)

The titlebar should have: Envelope, Name, Rep, Badges, Logout, About, FAQ and Search
But it only has: About, FAQ, Search.

Comment: i noticed this too. what's the deal?

Comment: The "I'm a Human Being" page has the same issue.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/why-does-my-user-info-disappear-when-viewing-a-badge